# Shopify getJSON('/cart.js') custom values of liquids

Tags: javascript, json, shopify, cart

Good time of day.
Trying to improve the pop-up cart was stuck on the possibility of using custom values instead of existing ones.
This example works as expected:

```
$.getJSON('/cart.js').then(
    function(cart) {
$('#example').html(theme.Currency.formatMoney(cart.total_price, theme.moneyFormat));
    });
```

In the cart template, I have made other values by liquid codes. Here is an example:

```
           {% for item in cart.items %}
           {% assign totalfive = 0 %}
           {% assign fiveminus = cart.total_price | times: 0.05 %}
           {% assign totalfive = cart.total_price | minus: fiveminus %}
           {% endfor %}
```

In HTML, this value  looks like this: `<span>{{ totalfive | money }}</span>`
The question is about how can I get this value by JSON? Maybe there is a way to catch it with an element based on ID? Or it definitely impossible?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What do you mean by "get this value by JSON"

Comment: How can I get <span> {{ totalfive | money }}</span> on popup?This cannot be output using .text() or .html() ...

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. It's not clear at all what you're asking/trying to accomplish

Comment: If you want the HTML response make a request to the `/cart` page instead of the `/cart.js`.